# Hazard Ratio Network Meta-analysis using gemtc package: how to fix 'undefined columns selected'

Tags: r

I need your help. Here is my data

```
  study treatment      diff   std.err
1     1         1 0.9847685 0.1951274
2     1         2        NA        NA
3     2         3 1.5100066 0.2593094
4     2         2        NA        NA
```

Here is my treatement

```
  id description
1  1        SCLC
2  2       NSCLC
3  3  Pemetrexed
```

When I try to establish a model like this:

```
model <-mtc.model(network,type="consistency", factor = 2.5, n.chain=4,likelihood="binom",link="cloglog",linearModel="fixed")
```

It just shows:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(data, sel1 | sel2, columns, drop = FALSE) : 
>     undefined columns selected

How to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: how did you create `network`? the docs say it should be class `mtc.network`

Comment: hi, i create network  this 'network <- mtc.network(data, description="Example", treatments=treatments)'

Comment: the data was input using 'read.csv'. Does it matter?